# Automatic site builder failing to create .htaccess files locally

Tags: htaccess

I have a vagrant box with PHP code building a site in it.

The user is vagrant with id:

```
uid=900(vagrant) gid=900(vagrant) groups=900(vagrant),27(sudo),1002(admin)
```

The parent directory in question exists but when trying to create an .htaccess file the code claims the directory is not writable (but recognises it exists).

```
  if (file_exists($directory) && is_writable($directory) && file_put_contents($htaccess_path, $htaccess_lines)) {
    return drupal_chmod($htaccess_path, 0444);
  }
```

The directory permissions are `drwxrwxr-x`. And the owner/group are `1001` and `vagrant_group` respectively.

Other PHP code, executed during the set-up, successfully creates files and directories inside the directory in question. This problem only happens when trying to create an .htaccess file.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: *".... the code claims ..."* - there is no code in your question. It is unclear what the code is actually doing - apart from that it behaves differently from your expectation. Thus either your expectations are wrong or the code is wrong and nothing more can be said with the amount of information you provide.

Comment: I didn't include the code because that's just PHP is_writable() and file_exists() checks but fair enough...

Comment: According to your description the directory should only be writable if the owner or group match. Neither match based on your description, i.e. owner is `1001` vs `900` and group is `vagrant_group` vs. `vagrant`.

Comment: You're not wrong. Except other code successfully creates files in this folder.

Anyway I "solved" it by hooking in a script that added the vagrant user to vagrant_group. Though I would prefer to understand why it failed than use a workaround like this.

Comment: I would rather be curious how other code managed to create files in this folder. While you don't provide any details about the other code it might just be that this other code runs with different permissions (i.e. different user or group).